# Append new data from a logfile to another file

Tags: linux, windows, lua

How to find out if new data was written into a logfile and how to extract these new data and write them to another file?

My goal is to create a big logfile for debugging purposes, because the current logfile always deletes data if the file reached a specific size.

My only idea is to create a copy from the old logfile every few minutes.

Comment: Instead of thinking of copying I would suggest you find out what process deletes the data if you need that data. Typically logfiles are "rotated" by the `logrotate` setup, a cron based scheduled task that rotates and compresses log files. You can alter its configuration. Just take a look inside the folders `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d`. You can remove the job that deletes the data or change it such that it only rotates instead of deleting or whatever you like.

Comment: i don't have this file in my device.

Comment: Then there must be some other thing than `logrotate` that is responsible for deleting the data. Data does not simply vanish by magic. I would take a look at that...

Answer (score 1):

quick & dirty way is to type the following line in your console - replacing "path/to/..." and "other/path/..." with the actual paths and log files:

```
* * * * * /path/to/small_file.log >> /other/path/to/big_file.log
```

It won't perform the IO every write, but it will do it every minute, which may or may not be sufficient for your needs.

EDIT: Tried to find a better method using C, here's what I got so far (read my comment in the post for more info).

```
//Include the full pathname and file for LOG_BIG and LOG_SMALL
#define LOG_BIG "/var/.../log_example_big.txt"
#define LOG_SMALL "/var/.../log_example_small.txt"
//FIXME: change LOG_BIG and LOG_SMALL to match the locations of the logfiles

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

time_t last_mod_time(const char *path);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char outstr[200];
    time_t t;
    struct tm *tmp;

    t = time(NULL);
    tmp = localtime(&t);

    // check for local time set failure
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        perror("localtime");
        return 0;
    }
    //if the returned size_t for strftime is 0, we exit
    if (strftime(outstr, sizeof(outstr), argv[1], tmp) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
        return 0;
    }
    double diff_log_mod_time;
    // get the difference of last modified time between LOG_BIG and LOG_SMALL
    diff_log_mod_time = difftime(last_mod_time(LOG_BIG),last_mod_time(LOG_SMALL));

    //difference in log modification times should be close to 0 +/- 10 ... I think
    if(fabs(diff_log_mod_time) > 10.0) {

        /* to finish the code, we would need to find the difference between the data in LOG_BIG and LOG_SMALL (assuming that LOG_BIG should contain all of LOG_SMALL and then some) */

    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/**
 * last_mod_time - this function finds the last modification time for a filename specified and returns 
 * it in epoch time (seconds lapsed since 1/1/1970)
 */
time_t last_mod_time(const char *path) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) == -1) {
        perror(path);
        exit(1);
    }
    return statbuf.st_mtime;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, i get `-sh: *: not found`

Comment: Sorry, I posted without testing it first. After looking in to it some more, I wasn't able to find a complete solution with shell scripting, so I decided to code it out in C. I was successful in getting the last modified dates of the two log files and checking the difference between them - this is helpful in determining whether or not there is really a difference between the two files to begin with. I'll provide a better explanation tomorrow, but here's what I got thus far - hope it helps.

Comment: Seems like he means adding this to crontab. See [How to redirect output to a file from within cron?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/159562) I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick and dirty way for achieving this would be to do the following:

```
cp /path/to/small_file.log /other/path/to/big_file.log;
nohup tail -f /path/to/small_file.log >> /other/path/to/big_file.log &
```